# Fluid Simulation issues

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation, gpu

Real quick, here's a snapshot of my specs:

- CPU: Intel i7-10700
- GPU: Gigabyte 2070 Super 8GB
- RAM: Samsung 16GB

Now I'm still new to blender and to simulations and what not, but I was following along to CG Geek's Fluid Sim tutorial, and coming across some issues. I used virtually the same settings as him (mostly lower, especially for particles) and had no issues until rendering.

I have my simulation set for 200 frames (liquid resolution at 128 samples), and it gets really busy at around frame 90-100 (as expected). So, while using the GPU to render, I noticed that the first 50 or so frames were very smooth... maybe about 30 seconds each. Then as it got closer to frame 90, the render times started getting longer and longer, and then at frame 98, I kept getting CUDA errors (I have Optix enabled).

I spent 2 hours reading and debugging and fiddling with tile size before just giving up and switching to CPU rendering.

My questions:

1. Is my setup not powerful enough for fluid simulations? Or are fluid simulations just THAT demanding?
2. Have any of you encountered any type of CUDA-related errors during your renders? I was getting a mix of timeout and synchronization issues. Tons of googling pointed me to lowering the tile size, but it didn't help too much. I even fiddled with the TDR in the registry, and that seemed promising, but then the render just became unresponsive altogether. (It didn't crash, it just ... stopped updating).
3. In the render window, the Mem: XXX and Peak: XXX numbers are referring to the VRAM usage, right? I noticed that whenever it would crash/stop working, my peak was ~5100M. Now my GPU has ~8GB of VRAM, and I understand that my computer uses it for various things, but should I be running into GPU memory issues?

Sorry for the wall of text. I'm just trying to learn as much as I can! :)